# Image text remove on hover

Tags: html, css

On the image, I have some content i.e. LTC. When I hover on the image, the thumbnail appears which have some contents like text and button. I want that when I hover on the image, the text on image i.e. LTC should not be shown.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="view view-eighth">
        <div class="main" style="background-image:url('image/ltc.jpg');">
            <div class="main-text">LTC</div>
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>ABC</h2>
                <div class="hover-text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
            </div>                
        </div>        
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that handles your hover state?

Comment: add opacity to 0 to main-tex on hover of view element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below `CSS` codes to your desired action:

```
.main:hover .main-text {
    display: none;
}
```

If you wanna do this smoothly use following code:

```
.main:hover .main-text {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

But if you need to really remove your `LTC` word from your `DOM` you should use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`, see below code:

```
$('.main').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.main-text').remove();
});
```

However, if you don't need to `jQuery` you can use below `Vanilla Js`:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.main');

el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    document.querySelector('.main-text').remove();
});
```

Comment: The OP said that "LTC" should not display

Comment: Sorry, but what is OP and LTC?

Comment: OP means "Original Poster" (i.e., author of question) and "LTC" is nothing but the text inside `.main-text`, OP said that *I want that when i hover on the image, the text on image i.e. LTC should not be shown.*

Comment: @rv7, thanks a lot, I didn't pay attention to `LTC` word. thanks.

Comment: I want to remove this " <div class="main-text">LTC</div>" on hover

Comment: @Bhawesh, see the update, maybe the answer update helps you.

Comment: where  ??   On js fiddle

Comment: @Bhawesh, no on here, my answer in this question that you asked.

Comment: var ltc = $('.main').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.main-text').remove();
});

Comment: this script is to use

Comment: maybe you do not import `jQuery` file inside your project. If you added, maybe you should put the code inside `document.ready`.

Comment: @Bhawesh, now see the new update, I put a pure `JavaScript` code if you don't need `jQuery`, please put this code in the bottom of your `HTML` codes. where before you close the body tag.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible that whenever i hover the mouse text dissapear but when i leave, text will  appear

Comment: @Bhawesh, I had bad flu, sorry for late answer, I'm amazed by your code, everything works in MacBook well, because with `remove()` function it remove from the `DOM`, seriously how it can back to the `DOM`?